# Segment Intersection — Failing on Unknown Edge Cases

Tags: java, programming-challenge, computational-geometry

I was recently at a programming competition. One of the problems was to determine whether two line segments are parallel, intersect, or do not intersect.

For all of the test cases I ran, my solution worked. However, when I submitted it, it was rejected (but no other information was given). I suspect there is either some edge case I am completely missing... or perhaps the judges messed up.

Input is entered as follows:

`ax ay bx by cx cy dx dy`

where the first segment is given by $$(a_x, a_y), (b_x, b_y)$$ and the second by $$(c_x, c_y), (d_x, d_y)$$

Some other rules/assumptions:

- We may assume that no segment has length zero; that is, each segment has distinct endpoints.
- Segments may share endpoint(s) with the other segment. Endpoints are included in the segment and thus are able to intersect (this also means that a segment whose endpoint lies within the other segment will intersect)
- Lines which both intersect and are parallel (either partial or complete overlap) should be considered parallel.
- All coordinates are integers on the open interval `(-1000, 1000)`.

*Here's a screenshot of the problem. Note that I'm ignoring the multiple tests option because I **highly** doubt that was the issue.* [image]

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class QP1505
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        int ax = in.nextInt();
        int ay = in.nextInt();
        int bx = in.nextInt();
        int by = in.nextInt();
        int cx = in.nextInt();
        int cy = in.nextInt();
        int dx = in.nextInt();
        int dy = in.nextInt();

        in.close();

        /*
         * Cross multiply to check equal slopes This takes care of
         * +/- infinity as well as zero
         */
        if ((by - ay) * (dx - cx) == (dy - cy) * (bx - ax))
        {
            System.out.println("PARALLEL");
        }
        else
        {
            double m1 = (double) (by - ay) / (bx - ax);
            double m2 = (double) (dy - cy) / (dx - cx);

            // Find point of intersection
            double x, y;
            if (Double.isInfinite(m1))
            {
                x = ax;
                y = m2 * (x - cx) + cy;
            }
            else if (Double.isInfinite(m2))
            {
                x = cx;
                y = m1 * (x - ax) + ay;
            }
            else
            {
                x = (m1 * ax - ay - m2 * cx + cy) / (m1 - m2);
                y = m1 * (x - ax) + ay;
            }

            // Check bounds
            if (((x >= ax && x <= bx) || (x <= ax && x >= bx))
                    && ((y >= ay && y <= by) || (y <= ay && y >= by))
                    && ((x >= cx && x <= dx) || (x <= cx && x >= dx))
                    && ((y >= cy && y <= dy) || (y <= cy && y >= dy)))
            {
                System.out.println("INTERSECT");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("DO NOT INTERSECT");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

And some test cases:

- Vertical Horizontal, Intersect

  ```
  0 0 0 5 -1 2 1 2
  INTERSECT
  ```
- Vertical Horizontal, No Intersect

  ```
  0 0 0 5 1 2 4 2
  DO NOT INTERSECT
  ```
- Horizontal Horizontal, Parallel

  ```
  0 0 5 0 1 1 5 1
  PARALLEL
  ```
- Vertical Regular, Intersect

  ```
  0 0 0 5 1 0 -1 4
  INTERSECT
  ```
- Vertical Regular, No Intersect

  ```
  0 0 0 5 1 0 4 6
  DO NOT INTERSECT
  ```
- Horizontal Regular, Intersect

  ```
  4 4 7 4 4 3 6 5
  INTERSECT
  ```
- Horizontal Regular, No Intersect

  ```
  2 2 8 2 3 3 9 6
  do not intersect
  ```
- Regular Regular, Intersect

  ```
  2 1 4 3 1 2 5 1
  INTERSECT
  ```
- Regular Regular, Parallel

  ```
  1 2 5 6 3 2 5 4
  PARALLEL
  ```
- Regular Regular, No Intersect

  ```
  1 2 5 6 3 2 8 5
  DO NOT INTERSECT
  ```

Let me know if anything else needs to be clarified (or any other test cases).

Comment: To be on-topic for Code Review, the code must be working properly to the best of your knowledge. There is some leeway for unforeseen corner cases, but you would have to prove that your code is basically correct.

Comment: It does work, for every single test case I have run. But should it be migrated to stack overflow, perhaps?

Comment: Prove it then. Also, if the challenge exists online, please link to it so we can see the exact specifications.

Comment: That works. I'll post a bunch of test cases. Also, the problem is not available online as it was just released this morning.

Comment: Don't use slope–intercept representation, use vectors! [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/565282/68063).

Comment: Make sure when you use @GarethRees answer that he linked that you use `double`s all the way to avoid `int` wraparound, and be careful when you divide.

Comment: ...or BigInteger or BigDecimal

Comment: Did the contest organizers say that the points were restricted in any way? Are they guaranteed to be integers? Are they in a specific range?

Comment: Problem was just released online; see edit.

Comment: Your code outputs the words in lowercase; the problem description requires uppercase.

Comment: Haha that was just a thing I changed when I uploaded it here. During the competition, I followed all formatting precisely. But I should go make that change now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Failure cases

I ran your program and was able to find an endless number of failures.  My technique was to have one line touch the origin `(0,0)` and then generate all lines that pass directly through the origin by simply choosing mirrored coordinates.  I was hoping to find roundoff errors and I did.  Here are just a small sampling of failure cases, all of which print "Do not intersect" instead of "intersect":

```
0 0 0 5 7 29 -7 -29
0 0 0 5 11 -30 -11 30
0 0 0 5 11 -15 -11 15
0 0 0 5 11 25 -11 -25
0 0 0 5 13 -30 -13 30
0 0 0 5 13 -15 -13 15
0 0 0 5 13 27 -13 -27
0 0 0 5 14 29 -14 -29
0 0 0 5 19 21 -19 -21
0 0 0 5 21 23 -21 -23
0 0 0 5 21 27 -21 -27
0 0 0 5 22 -30 -22 30
0 0 0 5 22 -15 -22 15
0 0 0 5 22 25 -22 -25
0 0 0 5 23 -26 -23 26
0 0 0 5 23 -13 -23 13
0 0 0 5 23 27 -23 -27
0 0 0 5 25 -29 -25 29
0 0 0 5 25 7 -25 -7
0 0 0 5 25 14 -25 -14
0 0 0 5 25 28 -25 -28
0 0 0 5 26 -30 -26 30
0 0 0 5 26 -15 -26 15
0 0 0 5 26 27 -26 -27
0 0 0 5 27 29 -27 -29
0 0 0 5 28 29 -28 -29
0 0 0 5 29 15 -29 -15
```

### Floating point?

My personal opinion about solving this problem correctly is that if your coordinates are constrained to be within -1000..1000, then you can do the whole problem using integers and not use floating point at all.

What you would need to do is create a fraction class that holds a numerator and denominator.  The fraction class needs to be able to: multiply, divide, add, subtract, compare (i.e. everything you are doing with your doubles).  Since the range of coordinates is so small, you shouldn't have a problem with overflow.  By doing this you will be safe from roundoff errors.

Comment: ...and that must have been it. Amazing. One of the judges suggested we should have used fractions, but I didn't even think of that sort of test.

Comment: @baum It's hard to get floating point numbers to not have roundoff errors.  I think the parallel slopes test was ok (and it could have been done with integers).  But finding the intersection point involved division and that's where you start to not be able to represent things exactly.

Comment: Out of curiosity, if the magnitude of the coordinates was not restricted, would there be any foolproof way of solving this problem? Perhaps BigInteger fractions? I'm thinking segments whose endpoints lie incredibly close to each other but are extremely far from the origin.

Comment: @baum Depending on the situation, a `long` might suffice.  If not, then `BigInteger` would work.

Comment: The problem is that `m` can't be computed exactly, so `x` is not computed exactly either (it would have to be exactly 0 in order to work). Good job, enjoy your bounty.

Answer (score 6):

#### Abstraction

Code that's well abstracted is easier to maintain, ...and to debug. I'd start by defining what a *segment* is - it's an immutable data structure with 2 *points*, where each *point* is defined by `X` and `Y` values (I'm sure [java](/questions/tagged/java) has something like a `Point` class built-in somewhere).

So I would take this chunk:

> ```
>     Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
>
>     int ax = in.nextInt();
>     int ay = in.nextInt();
>     int bx = in.nextInt();
>     int by = in.nextInt();
>     int cx = in.nextInt();
>     int cy = in.nextInt();
>     int dx = in.nextInt();
>     int dy = in.nextInt();
>
>     in.close();
> ```

And extract it into its own `getSegments` method, so that this:

> ```
> if ((by - ay) * (dx - cx) == (dy - cy) * (bx - ax))
> ```

Can look something like this:

```
if (isParallel(segment1, segment2))
```

And then you would have `isParallel` on its own, and you could write a dozen unit tests just for that method, covering every possible edge case.

---

Then you can extract another `findIntersectionPoint` method here, which would return a `Point`:

> ```
>     double m1 = (double) (by - ay) / (bx - ax);
>     double m2 = (double) (dy - cy) / (dx - cx);
>
>     // Find point of intersection
>     double x, y;
>     if (Double.isInfinite(m1))
>     {
>         x = ax;
>         y = m2 * (x - cx) + cy;
>     }
>     else if (Double.isInfinite(m2))
>     {
>         x = cx;
>         y = m1 * (x - ax) + ay;
>     }
>     else
>     {
>         x = (m1 * ax - ay - m2 * cx + cy) / (m1 - m2);
>         y = m1 * (x - ax) + ay;
>     }
> ```

And then you can cover that method with another dozen unit tests, and - assuming the "check bounds" part is also extracted into its own method, simplify the calling code to this:

```
Point intersection = findIntersectionPoint(segment1, segment2);
if (intersects(intersection, segment1, segment2))
{
    // intersect
}
else
{
    // no intersect
}
```

And then you can bombard `findIntersectionPoint` and `intersects` with another dozen unit tests to cover all edge cases.

---

The key point in this answer is granularity: you have one single method that *seems* to work, but it's doing many things that can't be tested individually - so even if you *do* end up figuring out a failing test, you wouldn't know exactly where the problem is and where to start looking.

Defining a `Segment` object might be over-the-top, but I find it simplifies the code, at least how it reads: seeing `segment2.point1.x` instead of `cx` makes it much easier to mentally map the values.. at least in *my* poor little fried brain.

---

One thing that strikes me, as a [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) programmer, is that your curly braces are... [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)-style. Typically [java](/questions/tagged/java) code would look something like this:

```
if (Double.isInfinite(m1)) {
    x = ax;
    y = m2 * (x - cx) + cy;
} else if (Double.isInfinite(m2)) {
    x = cx;
    y = m1 * (x - ax) + ay;
} else {
    x = (m1 * ax - ay - m2 * cx + cy) / (m1 - m2);
    y = m1 * (x - ax) + ay;
}
```

Comment: That's useful... I'll try doing that. As for braces style, that's how my professor likes them (though he's not originally a Java programmer either)

Answer (score 6):

As it was already pointed out, computing the slope of the line
segments (as a `double`) is problematic because the slope can be
"infinite" for vertical segments, and because of rounding errors.

My suggestion is to use a different algorithm which does not compute
the slope. If the coordinates are integers then all intermediate values 
are integers as well and no rounding errors can occur.
(I would choose the same algorithm for floating point coordinates because
it does not need any special cases for vertical or nearly vertical segments.)

The idea is to describe the line segment from \$(a_x, a_y) \$  to \$ (b_x, b_y) \$
in its parametric form 
$$
(x, y) = (a_x, a_y) + u (b_x - a_x, b_y - a_y) \, \quad  \text{where } 0 \le u \le 1 \,.
$$
Then the intersection of two line segments is a solution of
the linear equation system
$$
  (b_x - a_x) u - (d_x - c_x) v = c_x - a_x \\
  (b_y - a_y) u - (d_y - c_y) v = c_y - a_y 
$$
with \$ 0 \le u \le 1 \$ and \$ 0 \le v \le 1 \$. In the general case,
the solution is given by
$$
  u = \frac {\Delta_u} \Delta \, , \quad v = \frac {\Delta_v} \Delta
$$
with the determinants
$$
 \Delta = \begin{vmatrix} 
 b_x - a_x & d_x - c_x \\
 b_y - a_y & d_y - c_y
 \end{vmatrix} \, , \quad
 \Delta_u = \begin{vmatrix} 
 c_x - a_x & d_x - c_x \\
 c_y - a_y & d_y - c_y
 \end{vmatrix} \, , \quad
 \Delta_v = \begin{vmatrix} 
 c_x - a_x & b_x - a_x \\
 c_y - a_y & b_y - a_y
 \end{vmatrix} 
$$ 
If \$ \Delta = 0\$ then the line segments are parallel. Otherwise there is a unique
solution \$u, v \$ to the linear equation system, and it easy to check if the solutions
fall in the range \$ [0, 1] \$ without actually performing the division.

This leads to the following simple function:

```
static void checkIntersection(int ax, int ay, int bx, int by, int cx, int cy, int dx, int dy) {
    int det = (bx - ax)*(dy - cy) - (by - ay)*(dx - cx);
    if (det != 0) {
        /*
         * Lines intersect. Check if intersection point is on both segments:
         */
        int detu = (cx - ax)*(dy - cy) - (cy - ay)*(dx - cx);
        int detv = (cx - ax)*(by - ay) - (cy - ay)*(bx - ax);
        if (det < 0) {
            // Normalise to det>0 to simplify the following check.
            det = -det;
            detu = -detu;
            detv = -detv;
        }
        if (detu >= 0 && detu <= det && detv >= 0 && detv <= det) {
            System.out.println("INTERSECT");
        } else {
            System.out.println("NO NOT INTERSECT");
        }
    } else {
        /*
         * Lines are parallel (or identical):
         */
        System.out.println("PARALLEL");
    }
}
```

For integer coordinates in the range \$ -1000 \ldots 1000 \$, 
all the calculations can be done without overflow. 
Generally, for coordinates in a range \$ -M \ldots M \$,
the computed values are bounded by \$ 8M^2\$ in absolute value, so you can choose the
required type accordingly.

Comment: I just noticed that this is exactly what Gareth suggested in a [comment to the question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/87975/segment-intersection-failing-on-unknown-edge-cases/88312#comment159770_87975), slightly simpler here because we don't have to check if *parallel* segments overlap or not. I apologize for not noticing that earlier.

Comment: Also note that in the event you're not restricted to (-1000,1000) for each coordinate, you do need to handle wraparound on addition/subtraction, and overflow on multiplication.

Comment: @Snowbody: Sure, that's what I tried to express (perhaps badly) in the last paragraph.

Answer (score 4):

Okay I found some actual examples. with integer coordinates.

### EXAMPLE #1 - Wraparound

Let's try the most extreme case, where one of the segments is: `(INTEGER.MIN_VALUE,0) (Integer.MAX_VALUE,1)`. The slope *should* be positive and nearly zero, but calculation fails spectacularly. In an effort to avoid integer division, the code casts the numerator to a `double`, but the problem is that the *subtractions* are still being performed using `int` arithmetic:

```
        double m1 = (double) (by - ay) / (bx - ax);
        m1 = (double)(1-0)/(Integer.MAX_VALUE-Integer.MIN_VALUE);
```

Here, Java wraps around:

```
        m1 = (1.0)/(-1);
        m1 = -1.0;
```

I don't think we need to continue here; the calculation of `x` will obviously be wrong. The wraparound could be avoided by making sure that the individual elements are each cast to `double` or `java.Math.BigInteger`, so that all arithmetic is performed with `double`s or `BigInteger`s, but there are still problems with that approach -- see below.

### EXAMPLE #2 - Roundoff error

In this example we make sure that wraparound doesn't happen, either by choosing an interval that doesn't overflow, or by casting to `double`. There's still a problem. Say we have `(0,0) (Integer.MAX_VALUE,1)` and `(0,0) (Integer.MAX_VALUE-1,1)`.

```
        double m1 = (double) (by - ay) / (bx - ax);
        m1 = (double)(1 - 0)/(Integer.MAX_VALUE-0);
        m1 = (double)(1)/Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        m1 = 1.0/Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        m1 = 0b0.0000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000;
        double m2 = (double) (dy - cy) / (dx - cx);
        m2 = (double)(1 - 0)/(Integer.MAX_VALUE-1-0);
        m1 = (double)(1)/(Integer.MAX_VALUE-1);
        m2 = 1.0/(Integer.MAX_VALUE-1);
        m2 = 0b0.0000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000;
```

These slopes are small, and very close to each other but not quite identical. They do differ in fact, but the difference is calculated as 0b0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001 = 2^-62 when really it's slightly larger than that (it's 2^-62 + 2^-92 + ...). So, `m1-m2` is either slightly too large or too small, which causes `x` to be either slightly too large or too small. So when the point of intersection is the endpoint of one of the segments, the algorithm determines the lines don't intersect, when in fact they do.

You can verify the binary floating point arithmetic using http://www.exploringbinary.com/binary-calculator/ . Do the calculation once to find out where the most significant digit is, then add on 53 more bits.

I also notice the parallel check needs wraparound protection, both on the subtractions and on the multiplications; with a little work I could find two segments that report as parallel when they're not, or report as non parallel when they are. If you cast everything to `double` you still run the risk of the 53 bits of precision not being enough (think about multiplying two 30-bit quantities). I think you may need to use [`java.math.BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) or [`java.math.BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) here.

Comment: While these over/underflow issues *do* seem to be legitimate concerns (and answer my question, so I'll probably grant bounty), the funny thing was that the contest organizers said that all coordinate points would be between -1000 and 1000. If no one finds anything else, perhaps *they* were in the wrong and I was right.

Comment: Don't award it to me yet, maybe someone will come along and spot an error with coordinate points in that range.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a dangerous method to obtain the point of intersection. Your method works fine when one of the slopes is calculated as `Infinite` but <strike>it's numerically unstable if the two slopes differ by many orders of magnitude (more than the 15-17 decimal digits that a Java double supports).</strike> This can't happen because all the coordinates are integers. Even the most extreme points can't cause roundoff error.

<strike>The problem is with the slopes. When you calculate `m1` and `m2` the subtractions and divisions may not be exact, which introduces some error into the slopes themselves. This is then compounded when the two slopes are then subtracted from each other `m1 - m2` in the quotient where you are calculating `x`. It's quite possible that this subtraction will remove all the signal and be left with only noise, which will make the calculated `x` completely invalid.</strike> While I wish this was true, because all the coordinates are `int`s the subtractions are exact, and the divisions don't introduce that much error.

<strike>How about the first segment being (0,1), (10^{17},10^{17}) and the second segment being (1,0), (10^{17},10^{17}). The lines are not parallel; they intersect at `x == 1e17, y == 1e17`. Since your test for parallel is correct, it will not print "parallel" -- so far so good. Unfortunately, due to the limits of Java's `double`, both `m1` and `m2` will be calculated as `1.0000000000`. Your program will crash when it tries to compute `x` due to the divide by zero.</strike>

That doesn't work, outside range for `int` plus they'd be detected as `parallel`. No bounty for me.

Comment: This answer was completely wrong (though it would be correct if the inputs had been `double`s). Please downvote this one and upvote my other answer.

Comment: If you ask for it so kindly... ;)

Comment: @Snowbody You can always delete this one...

Comment: Eh, I wanted to point out the hazards of widely varying slopes.